# Problem when trying to input a time in ant timepicker

Tags: vue.js, antd

For some reason I can not edit a time when I use [ant design time picker](https://www.antdv.com/components/time-picker/). I think this is coming from the v-model or the way I update the changes made on the input...

The initialization of the fields works but when I click on it nothing happens...

[image]

This is what I've tried so far :

```
<a-time-picker v-model="newAddress.deliveryTimeFrom" use12Hours format="h:mm a" @change="updateDeliveryTimeFrom" />
<a-time-picker v-model="newAddress.deliveryTimeTo" use12Hours format="h:mm a" @change="updateDeliveryTimeTo"/>

    data(){
        return{
            newAddress:{
                deliveryTimeFrom: moment().hour(8).minutes(0),
                deliveryTimeTo: moment().hour(9).minutes(0),
            },
        }
    },

    methods:{

        updateDeliveryTimeFrom(time){
            this.newAddress.deliveryTimeFrom = time;
            this.newAddress.deliveryTimeTo = moment(time, "hh:mm A")
                .add(30, 'minutes');
        },
        updateDeliveryTimeTo(time){
            this.newAddress.deliveryTimeTo = time;
        }
    },
```

Thanks for the help !

Comment: what is wrong?.

Comment: @ChristianCarrillo I've edited the post. Thanks !